# firebase get data where field equal to something satisfies

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore currently I have this code:

```
import firebase_admin
import google.cloud
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import datetime

cred = credentials.Certificate("ServiceAccountKey.json")
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

store = firestore.client()
doc_ref = store.collection(u'accidents')

try:
    docs = doc_ref..get()
    for doc in docs:
        print(u'Doc Data:{}'.format(doc.to_dict()))
except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print(u'Missing data')
```

now what I want to do is get data where field vehicle is equals to BGA284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query where vehicle is equals to BGA284, try the following:

```
doc_ref = store.collection(u'accidents').where(u'vehicle', u'==', u'BGA284')
```